# Change password of a Git user

Tags: git, debian

After I installed Git on my Debian server. Here is what I have done so far:

```
sudo apt-get install git

sudo adduser --system --shell /bin/bash --group --disabled-password --home /var/git/ git
sudo chown git:git /var/git

ssh-keygen -t rsa

chmod 755 ~/.ssh
chmod 600 ~/.ssh/id_rsa
chmod 644 ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub

sudo mkdir /var/git/.ssh
sudo touch /var/git/.ssh/authorized_keys

echo "_CONTENT_OF_MY_PUBLIC_KEY_HERE_" >> /var/git/.ssh/authorized_keys

chmod 755 ~/.ssh
chmod 644 ~/.ssh/authorized_keys

ssh git@my-server.com
```

that's works well, but when I try connect, with this:

```
ssh git@my-server.com
```

That ask me a password, and I don't know what to write (I have tried my public key, nothing and my root password but that's doesn't work).

How can i change the password, or where can I find it?

Comment: Offtopic. Not a programming question. Configuring passwordless logins for SSH is not programming - that's system configuration.

Comment: @Marck B give him a break, it's a valid programming question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run `passwd git` as root in order to change the password of the `git` user.

However, it's rather unconventional. Usually logins using a ssh key are preferred (not just for security reasons, some git frameworks like gitolite rely on that in order to detect which user is accessing the repository for authorization).

The reason why you public key is not working is, that `/var/git/.ssh/authorized_keys` is not owned by the git user (run `chown git:git /var/git/.ssh/authorized_keys` to fix this)